# Filter and Slicer don't have an effect on published charts

Tags: google-sheets

I got some database which automatically updating, and I need to publish some charts, based on it. BUT, No filter or slicer does not work in published charts. So I'm looking for something that can help me with that, mb any macros or scripts that automatically (every hour) takes filtered data and creating a chart which I can publish...

1. create a database
2. make slicer based on date and checkbox
3. create chart
4. publish chart

And here it is, chart takes data from full table, instead of filtered one

Comment: have you tried this? separate the records based on date and checkbox, populate these records in separate sheet, then create/modify chart to use that separated data instead of the whole database.

Comment: Sure, it will work, but this database is updating automaticaly, and i thought i can create chart that will update with this.

Answer (score 0):

Slicers and Filters manipulate data visually, it does not affect rows.

Charts will bypass the visually hidden rows and show the data as it is.

Hence Like I suggested in comments, here is an example:

1. **main data** is a sheet where your data is automatically updated
2. **filtered data** is a sheet where the filtered data as on pre-defined/selectable filter is loaded
3. **chart** is the chart sheet where the data is visualized as column chart

chart sheet can be published as interactive/web page (it auto-refreshes every 5 min)

Link to experimental sheet : [Auto-Update Published Chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FRQuKNA2LSqZF8_j9hU3gzR_pvrwpNIzezZx-mDUFUw)

Link to published chart : [Auto-Update Published Chart : chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTYtQa-mo44QgvXEyJVMhvOXLKPitAwiO3ArNTNWJ9EsGZTjzt5dbmgK8MGL9RtHtLz1SifMk9aPVRs/pubhtml?gid=860700633&single=true)